# Correlation between the the columns of the matrix when there are columns with constant value ( Very Slow!)

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a customized correlation code in python that does not return "nan", infact it returns 0 whenever it tries to calculate the correlation between any two columns where either or both of them are constant

```
def getCorreCustom(matrix,columns=30):
  A=np.zeros((columns,columns))
  for i in range(columns):
    for j in range(columns):
      if i==j:
        A[i,j]=1
      else:
        a=matrix[:,i]
        b=matrix[:,j]

        if np.std(a)==0 or np.std(b)==0:
          A[i,j]=0
        else:
          A[i,j]=scipy.stats.spearmanr(a,b).correlation
  return A
```

SO when I try to use the built in numpy correlation  function , it puts "nan" values wherever it gets the constant column

```
Test=np.random.random((50,30))
Test[:,0]=1                          //deliberately setting constant column
Test[:,10]=1

np.corrcoef(Test.transpose()).shape
```

**Output using numpy.corrcoef**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2534: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  c /= stddev[:, None]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2535: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  c /= stddev[None, :]
(30, 30)
```

**My customized correlation coefficient**

```
R=getCorreCustom(Test)
R.shape    // 30 x 30
```

**Problem**

My code is working fine BUT the biggest issue that I am getting is that my code is extremely slow and on large matrices as I have requirement of size 100  x 30 and sometimes 170 x 30, it gets too slow.

So How can I make this code fast as the built-in numpy correlation code was I am sure vectorized and very fast?

Regard

Comment: You can safely do this by using `np.nan_to_num`, e.g., `np.nan_to_num(np.corrcoef(Test))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use pandas like this

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
Test = np.random.random((50, 30))
Test[:, 0] = 1
Test[:, 10] = 1
start_time = datetime.now()
R = getCorreCustom(Test)
print("Custom Method")
print(datetime.now() - start_time)
print(R.shape)
start_time = datetime.now()
P = pd.DataFrame(Test)
print("Pandas Method")
print(datetime.now() - start_time)
print(P.corr(method="spearman").fillna(0).shape)
```

Result is:

```
Custom Method
0:00:00.498294
(30, 30)
Pandas Method
0:00:00.000230
(30, 30)
```

This is 2166.495652173913 times faster than custom method on my computer.

Comment: issue is that it also gives nan values